# Get values from map function without rerendering too many useState React

Tags: reactjs

I am having a problem returning a value from a map function. It re-renders when I set the state from useState.

```
const [getPrice, setPrice] = useState([]);

    recordProcedures.map((item) => (
        item.chosen != null ?
        item.chosen.map((proc) =>(
            console.log('Inner Map:',proc),
            console.log('Procedure:',proc.procedure),
            console.log('Price:',proc.price)
        ))
        : null
    ))
```

this is what the console.log looks like [console.log preview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rQyMv.png)

Now if I set a state like this

```
const [getPrice, setPrice] = useState([]);

    recordProcedures.map((item) => (
        item.chosen != null ?
        item.chosen.map((proc) =>(
            console.log('Inner Map:',proc),
            console.log('Procedure:',proc.procedure),
            console.log('Price:',proc.price)
           setPrice(proc.price)
        ))
        : null
    ))
```

It renders multiple times and getting an error [console.log(getPrice)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tgHHL.png)
How can I return/get the value inside the map function without rerendering the use

Comment: Divide the problem into two halves, 1. Filter the array of chosen using array.filter, 2. Find the item you want in chosen array returned from first step using array.find, lastly setprice of it

Answer (score 0):

Hooks can only be called inside the body of a function component.
You can not directly call setState. Instead use `useEffect`

```
  useEffect(()=>{
     const price = recordProcedures?.map((item) => (
        item.chosen?.map((proc) =>proc.price)
    ))
    setPrice(price)
  }, [recordProcedures])
```

Comment: I added recordProcures inside the empty array of useEffect and it worked! Thank you so much

Comment: Yes, I did not see your previous code, if recordProcedures initially is undefined and then loaded, need to add dependency to  render each change of dependent state value.

Comment: If this answer is helpful, you can accept it as best answer.